# How can I do this properly to be able to select in DBSelectQuery class?

Tags: java, mysql, database, select, extends

I have 2 different classes. One is for the db connection and one is for querying. I want to be able to  select a query in the DBSelectQuery Class by extending it to DBConnection Class. How can I do it properly?

```
public class DBSelectQuery extends DBConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    selectCourier();
}
public static String selectCourier() {
    queryStmt += "SELECT * FROM courier";
    System.out.println(queryStmt);
    return queryStmt;
   }
}

public class DBConnection {
public static Connection con;
public static String queryStmt;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_activity", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("Database Connected");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryStmt);
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2));
        con.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One method I have used with a good degree of success is to create a static util class which exposes any number of methods for executing particular queries.  For your case, we will assume that you only need to execute one query, but you can easily extend this answer to any number of them.

The general strategy of the approach below is that each query which you think your application will need to execute gets its own method.  This may not seem logical for you simple example, but when you start using positional parameters, you sort of need to know the fixed structure of the query before going to use it.

There is a method for getting a connection, which would be called repeatedly as needed.  Each query method returns a `List<Object[]>`, where each row is represented by an object array.

```
public class DBUtil {
    private static final String GET_ALL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM courier";

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_activity",
                                              "root", "root");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }

    public static List<Object[]> getAll(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(GET_ALL_QUERY);
        List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] row = new Object[2];
            row[0] = (Object)rs.getInt(1);
            row[1] = (Object)rs.getString(2);
            list.add(row);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is how you might use the above util class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection();

    try {
        List<Object[]> resultSet = DBUtil.getAll(con);

        for (Object[] row : resultSet) {
            int val1 = (Integer)row[0];
            String val2 = (String)row[1];

            System.out.println("Found a row: (" + val1 + ", " + val2 + ")");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong during the query.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to make it 2 classes and want to make the select query reusable for selecting on other tables

Comment: @CarminaCastañeto No, I don't recommend that at all.  Just use a single class to handle your JDBC service stuff, unless you expect maybe more than 1000 lines of code.  And the queries should _not_ be viewed as "reusable."  Treat each query differently.

Comment: public static List<Object[]> getAll(Connection con) throws SQLException how do i call this method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate method which returns Connection object in DBConnection class:

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_activity", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("Database Connected");            
        con.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return con;

}
```

Now you can call this method anywhere in your project in any class.

```
public static String selectCourier() {
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    queryStmt += "SELECT * FROM courier";
    System.out.println(queryStmt);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryStmt);
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2));

    return queryStmt;   
}
```